# CaseInsensitive search in HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, hashcode, case-insensitive

I have a map:

```
static Map<String, String> = getMap(); //getting a map from a config file.
```

Now in this Map I need to perform a caseInsensitive search, using KEYS. I am NOT putting the values in map, not through put function, but you can think it as a values stored in data base in a key value format, and retrieving it as a Map. I need to do a caseInsentive search.

After researching, using a TreeMap would solve the problem, but not efficient --> O(log n)

or overring the get() method of HashMap, creating my own HashMap. but this would include overrding many methods, and I dont want this much, it not a part of very important code.

Right now I am im storing the values, in lowercase in database, and checking. But it makes it error prone, and not readble, in database.

Can there be a simpler method to do it?

Comment: Are you searching keys or values?

Comment: Have you looked at [CaseInsensitiveMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/CaseInsensitiveMap.html)?

Comment: What exactly are you searching for (in the key or the value)? Are you looking for a complete match or a partial match? Could you provide some examples in your question?

Comment: I am searching for a complete match, just to be case-insensitive. I am searching for keys. CaseInsensitive map is not generic, how can I use it?

Comment: The database is basically, a file, which stores it in that format.

Comment: It is generic in 4.0: [generic CaseInsensitiveMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CaseInsensitiveMap.html)

Comment: @Keppil, I am using JDK 1.7, when I try to import the generic version, it dosent allow me. I think its not there in JDK 1.7

Comment: It should work with 1.5 and above. Did you use the right import? [Maven link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0)

Comment: @Keppil How can I add dependecy for collection file in Config file? Where I add dependency for java version like: JDK = 1.7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.) `TreeMap` extends `Map` can be an option, but time complexity is `O(log n)`

```
final Map<String, Object> map = new TreeMap<String, Object>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

2.) You could use [CaseInsensitiveMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CaseInsensitiveMap.html) from Apache's Commons Collections as suggested above.

3.) Creating your own `HashMap` Class and overriding methods.

```
public class MyCaseInsensitiveMap extends HashMap<String, String> {
    ...
    put(String key, String value) {
       super.put(key.toLowerCase(), value);
    }

    get(String key) {
       super.get(key.toLowercase());
    }
}
```

4.) You need a wrapper class for your String key with a case-insensitive `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementation. Use that instead of the String for the Map's key.

example [here](http://java.happycodings.com/java-util-package/code3.html)

** There does not seems to be straight forward library available except for apache commons.

PS: Consolidated from other links available in SO also.

Comment: 1 -> No. 2-> Not generic. 3-> I am not putting the keys in the map through put function, but its stored in config file. 4-> I tried it but didnt work. I did something like : static Map<StringWrapper, StringWrapper> = getMap();

Comment: I think it didnt work because, not adding to map using put function, so values added are String format only, not StringWrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with O(1) but utilizing more space, this may help:

```
class CaseInsensitiveLookupMap {

private Map<String,String> keysMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
private Map<String,String> dataMap;

public CaseInsensitiveLookupMap(Map<String,String> dataMap){
  this.dataMap=dataMap;
  for(String key: dataMap.keySet()){
     keysMap.put(key.toLowerCase(),key);
  }
}

public String get(String keyToSearch){
  String _key = keysMap.get(keyToSearch.toLowerCase());
  if(_key!=null) {
    return dataMap.get(_key);
  }
  return null;
}

}
```